# SQL- How to split two dates into yearly format

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

If I have two dates for example:

```
@StartDate = '2009/01/01'
@EndDate = '2015/02/05'
```

is there a way for it to display in this format:

```
StartDate             EndDate
2009/01/01            2010/01/01 
2010/01/01            2011/01/01
2011/01/01            2012/01/01
2012/01/01            2013/01/01
2013/01/01            2014/01/01
2014/01/01            2015/01/01
2015/01/01            2015/02/05 <--- most importantly end using the end date
```

is this possible? because I have seen a number of CTE code snippets but they only split upto 01/01/2015 and not continue to the end of period 05/02/2015? Is there any possible chance for it include the remainder of the final period - 2015/01/01 - 2015/02/05 even though its not a year?

Comment: Which RDBMS and which version are you using?

Comment: Do you really want the end date to be the same as the next row's start date?

Comment: If its possible then +1 day after each increment (excluding the initial start date) may help... at the moment I'm more curious of getting the end part to show correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
with nums as (
      select 0 as n
      union all
      select 1 + n
      from nums
      where n < 100
     )
select DATEADD(year, n, @StartDate) as StartDate,
       (case when DATEADD(year, n+1, @StartDate) >= @EndDate then @EndDate
             else DATEADD(year, n+1, @StartDate)
        end) as EndDate
from nums
where dateadd(year, nums.n, @StartDate) < @EndDate
```

If your periods are really long, you might need to expand `nums` beyond 100 values.

Comment: Ah, this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks Gordon/bluefeet

Comment: If you wanted to remove the overlap and make the period end on 12/31, you can just change the ELSE portion to:  `else DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(year, n+1, @StartDate))`

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2009/01/01'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2015/02/05'

;WITH Dates AS
(
    SELECT
         StartDate = @StartDate,
         EndDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, @StartDate)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        StartDate = DATEADD(YEAR, 1, StartDate),
        EndDate = CASE 
                        WHEN DATEADD(YEAR, 1, EndDate) > @EndDate 
                             AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, EndDate) < DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @EndDate)  THEN @EndDate
                        ELSE DATEADD(YEAR, 1, EndDate) 
                    END
    FROM Dates
    WHERE EndDate < @EndDate
)

SELECT * FROM dates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16028)